docker nodejs - returned a non-zero code: 134
I have this very simple dockerfile:
FROM node:lts AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install --verbose
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node ./dist/server/entry.mjs


and docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  xxxxxx:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

I test this locally at my mac without problem.
but when I transfer over to my ubuntu server and run the sudo docker-compose up, I got this error:
  #  node[7]: std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start() at ../src/node_platform.cc:68
  #  Assertion failed: (0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))

----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0xe2fcd7 node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) [node]
 2: 0xeb54ce node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner(int) [node]
 3: 0xeb55ac node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*, v8::PageAllocator*) [node]
 4: 0xdd22b6  [node]
 5: 0xdd37b4 node::Start(int, char**) [node]
 6: 0x7f513d15624a  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 7: 0x7f513d156305 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 8: 0xd2717e _start [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: Service 'xxxxxx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --verbose' returned a non-zero code: 134

I googled a few rounds and only found a forum command mentioned that could be the node version issue. I checked my local version is 21.5 so I change the dockerfile:
from node:21.7

and still get the same issue.
the error happen when running the npm install
what seems to be the problem here? and How can I resolve this?
update01
I build the image locally and push it up to the server still get this error:
  #  node[8]: std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start() at ../src/node_platform.cc:68


  #  Assertion failed: (0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))




----- Native stack trace -----




 1: 0xcba0f7 node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) [node]


 2: 0xd3942e node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner(int) [node]


 3: 0xd3950c node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*, v8::PageAllocator*) [node]


 4: 0xc6e2d6  [node]


 5: 0xc6f7d4 node::Start(int, char**) [node]


 6: 0x7f4ef3aad24a  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]


 7: 0x7f4ef3aad305 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]


 8: 0xbc5c8e _start [node]


Aborted (core dumped)

what is the error about? can't seems to figure out the error message.

related to docker version being too old I trust => read this issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43064#issuecomment-1765844846

I believe the log is missing information. From experience, I think your problem is a lack of memory on the server.
The ideal would be for you to compile the image on your machine and pull the image to the server, without having to recompile it on the server.
Perform a test by changing the NPM memory parameters.
npm install - javascript heap out of memory

after a few tests, I suspect so too. I am using mac and trying to make it run with ubuntu server. not sure if compile image works like that. let me test and update here.

this link seems to be the solution
